# How to use the width of some text in \dim_compare:nTF directly?

Tags: expl3, width, dimensions

Is it possible to use the width of some text directly inside of a `<dimension expression>`. I found this way using a temporary box but it seems not very elegant …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% generate the new box
\box_new:N \tmp_box

% a dummy command to test
\NewDocumentCommand{ \getwidth }{ m }
 {
  % save argument to the box
  \hbox_set:Nn \tmp_box { #1 }
  % measure the box width
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \tmp_box < 10pt }
   { \textbf{smaller}~than~10pt }% do something cooler here
   { \textbf{greater}~than~10pt }% do somthing even cooler here
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The width of \emph{word} is \getwidth{word}.

The width of \emph{i} is \getwidth{i}.
\end{document}
```

I want to skip the `\hbox_set:Nn\tmp_box{#1}` line and use something like `\box_wd:n{#1}` but creating this variant didn’t work …

Comment: I think this is the usual way. I believe you'd have to measure the width of the argument expandably in order to use it in `\dim_compare:n(TF)` directly. I don't think this is possible, though...

Comment: @cgnieder OK, thanks. I posted a CW answer to get an acceptable answer, but you may post you comment as an answer and I’ll delete mine …

Comment: I might be wrong, of course :) That's why I only posted a comment. But someone will tell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no shorter way.

<sub>As cgnieder said I found the right way an there’s no shortcut. I post this CW answer to mark my question as aswered, though</sub>

Answer (score 5):

There's no function such as `\settowidth` or `\widthof`, but it's not difficult to implement a conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l__tobi_compare_box
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \tobi_dim_compare_wd:nn #1 #2 { T , F , TF }
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__tobi_compare_box { #1 }
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__tobi_compare_box #2 }
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getwidth}{m}
 {
  \tobi_dim_compare_wd:nnTF { #1 } { < 10pt }
   { \textbf{smaller}~than~10pt }% do something cooler here
   { \textbf{greater}~than~10pt }% do somthing even cooler here
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The width of \emph{word} is \getwidth{word}.

The width of \emph{i} is \getwidth{i}.
\end{document}
```

You have available `\tobi_dim_compare_wd:nn(TF)`. It's not expandable, but it can't be if you want to measure some text.

[image]

Comment: This, of course, is only a wrapper that does the same thing :)

Comment: @cgnieder It's an abstraction, that also defines a conditional usable in many other situations.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: it's a good solution and fits nicely in the expl3 philosophy! But it still does the same as in the question as there can't be an expandable `\box_width_of:n {}` that could be used in `\dim_eval:n {}`, doesn't it?

Comment: @cgnieder No, it can't be expandable, because the text must be typeset in a box.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. But as cnieger said its not shorter and a little overkill for my application so I'll stick to my approach – hope you don't mind ;-)

Comment: Is there a reason that a shortcut for this is missing in the kernel?

Comment: @Tobi There's nothing in expl3 regarding explicit typesetting, up to now.